# Split Regex, return only characters, digits and underscores. Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Attempting to break up the line

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w`

with the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %words;

while (my $line = <>)
{
foreach my $word (split /:|,\s*|\/|!|\#|-/, $line)
{
    $words{$word}++;
}
}

foreach my $word (keys %words)
{
print "$word: $words{$word}\n";
}
```

Is there an easier way to have the split command only split at words, numbers and underscores? Rather than setting all of these delimiters.

Attempting to get the output

```
usr: 1
bin: 1
perl: 1
```

Comment: (This was closed as a duplicate to a question whose answer is `split ' '`, which is not appropriate here. Re-opened.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't split, extract.

```
++$words{$_} for $line =~ /\w+/g;
```

Comment: So much more compact, love it. However, I can't figure a way to only output words greater than 1 character (so we would discard the -w).

Comment: `\w\w+` or simply `\w{2,}`

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Can you use extraction to convert all of the letters to lowercase as well?

Comment: No, but neither could `split`. Just do it outside (`++$words{lc($_)}`).

Comment: Ahh okay no worries! I was just seeing to what extent I could work this whole "extraction" method. Sorry about that

Comment: A regex match returns parts of the original string, just like `split`. The difference is that you specify what separates what you want with `split`, and you specify what you want with a regex match.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with split and the negated word [character class](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#Character-classes):

```
foreach my $word (split /\W+/, $line) {
  $words{$word}++;
}
```

But note that since your string starts with non-word characters, the first word it will return is the empty string at the beginning of the string.

Another tool for this task (but more suited to prose than code and filenames) is the [unicode word boundary](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#%5Cb%7Bwb%7D), which uses Unicode rules for where words start and end, and takes into account things like apostrophes being part of words (`can't`). To utilize this, you'd first need to split your input into a list containing both words and non-words, and then find the words (easiest way is probably to use any elements that contain at least one word character):

```
foreach my $word (grep { m/\w/ } split /\b{wb}/, $line) {
  $words{$word}++;
}
```

The `\b{wb}` regex sequence requires Perl 5.24+.

Comment: That doesn't handle strings that don't start with a word (such as the OP's example). /// Also, this approach doesn't lend itself to improving the definition of a word. All else being equal, a solution that can evolve is better.

Comment: I agree, but it's an option, and it is still extensible in some ways. For instance, if you change the definition of "word character" to include `:`: `split /[^\w:]+/, $line`

Comment: There are of course unicode considerations to `\w` and `\W`, but until the code in question is decoding its input from UTF-8, I'm assuming it's not a factor for this input...

Comment: That's hardly the way word parsers evolve, though. First, there's `'s`,...

Comment: @ikegami If you really want to do that right, there's the [unicode word boundary](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#%5Cb%7Bwb%7D) in recent Perls...

Comment: I don't want to expand the OP's definition that much, but since it works well with split, you might want to mention it?